# What is the default value for spark.sql.columnNameOfCorruptRecord?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have read the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#json(scala.collection.Seq)) but can not get `spark.sql.columnNameOfCorruptRecord` default value even with google searching.
The second question - how `PERMISSIVE` `mode` works when `spark.sql.columnNameOfCorruptRecord` is empty or null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L931) (19/01/2021) it's `_corrupt_record`:

```
val COLUMN_NAME_OF_CORRUPT_RECORD = buildConf("spark.sql.columnNameOfCorruptRecord")
  .doc("The name of internal column for storing raw/un-parsed JSON and CSV records that fail " +
  "to parse.")
  .version("1.2.0")
  .stringConf
  .createWithDefault("_corrupt_record")
```

Regarding how `PERMISSIVE` mode works, you can see this in `FailSafeParser[T]`:

```
def parse(input: IN): Iterator[InternalRow] = {
  try {
    rawParser.apply(input).toIterator.map(row => toResultRow(Some(row), () => null))
  } catch {
    case e: BadRecordException => mode match {
      case PermissiveMode =>
        Iterator(toResultRow(e.partialResult(), e.record))
      case DropMalformedMode =>
        Iterator.empty
      case FailFastMode =>
        throw new SparkException("Malformed records are detected in record parsing. " +
        s"Parse Mode: ${FailFastMode.name}. To process malformed records as null " +
        "result, try setting the option 'mode' as 'PERMISSIVE'.", e)
  }
}

private val toResultRow: (Option[InternalRow], () => UTF8String) => InternalRow = {
  if (corruptFieldIndex.isDefined) {
    (row, badRecord) => {
      var i = 0
      while (i < actualSchema.length) {
        val from = actualSchema(i)
        resultRow(schema.fieldIndex(from.name)) = row.map(_.get(i, from.dataType)).orNull
        i += 1
      }
      resultRow(corruptFieldIndex.get) = badRecord()
      resultRow
    }
  } else {
  (row, _) => row.getOrElse(nullResult)
  }
}
```

If it isn't specified, it'll fallback to the default value defined in the configuration.